# Kafka - Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition. NetworkException when send large data to kafka topic

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, file-upload, kafka-producer-api

I try to upload file using kafka. When I send large file to kafka I got exception like this.

2023-08-01 14:46:00.754  INFO 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cancelled in-flight PRODUCE request with correlation id 11886 due to node 0 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 28ms, elapsed time since send: 28ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2023-08-01 14:46:00.754  WARN 1 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Got error produce response with correlation id 11886 on topic-partition file_upload-1, retrying (2147483406 attempts left). Error: NETWORK_EXCEPTION. Error Message: Disconnected from node 0
2023-08-01 14:46:00.754  WARN 1 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition file_upload-1 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NetworkException: Disconnected from node 0. Going to request metadata update now

My Kafka Producer Configuration is like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    private static final String MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE = "314572800";

    private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    @Value("${kafka.file-upload-topic}")
    private String fileUploadTopic;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getBootstrapServers());
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getProperties().getOrDefault("max.request.size", MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE));
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getProperties().getOrDefault("max.request.size", MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE));

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        NewTopic newTopic = new NewTopic(fileUploadTopic, 5, (short) 1);
        Map<String, String> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put("max.message.bytes", MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE);
        newTopic.configs(configs);
        return newTopic;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

}
```

My Kafka Consumer Configuration is like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
@EnableRetry
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    private static final String MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE = "314572800";

    private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;
    private final az.bankrespublika.filehandler.config.properties.KafkaProperties properties;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getBootstrapServers());
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getProperties().getOrDefault("max.request.size", MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE));

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> fileConsumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getBootstrapServers());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, properties.getFileUploadGroup());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getProperties().getOrDefault("message.max.bytes", MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE));
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getProperties().getOrDefault("message.max.bytes", MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE));
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> fileInfoConsumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getBootstrapServers());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, properties.getFileInfoGroup());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getProperties().getOrDefault("message.max.bytes", MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE));
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getProperties().getOrDefault("message.max.bytes", MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE));
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaFileListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        kafkaListenerContainerFactory.setConsumerFactory(fileConsumerFactory());
        kafkaListenerContainerFactory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
        return kafkaListenerContainerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaFileInfoListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        kafkaListenerContainerFactory.setConsumerFactory(fileInfoConsumerFactory());
        kafkaListenerContainerFactory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
        return kafkaListenerContainerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic fileUploadTopic() {
        NewTopic newTopic = new NewTopic(properties.getFileUploadTopic(), 5, (short) 1);
        Map<String, String> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put("max.message.bytes", MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE);
        newTopic.configs(configs);
        return newTopic;
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic fileInfoTopic() {
        NewTopic newTopic = new NewTopic(properties.getFileInfoTopic(), 5, (short) 1);
        return newTopic;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

}
```

I have two microservices. ms-file and ms-file-handler

ms-file accept file and send it to kafka topic
ms-file-handler consume files from topic then upload to cloud storage

I can upload files to 60MB but i try to upload files over 100MB I can't do it
producer side throw exception as loop like this:

```
2023-08-01 14:46:00.754  INFO 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cancelled in-flight PRODUCE request with correlation id 11886 due to node 0 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 28ms, elapsed time since send: 28ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2023-08-01 14:46:00.754  WARN 1 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Got error produce response with correlation id 11886 on topic-partition file_upload-1, retrying (2147483406 attempts left). Error: NETWORK_EXCEPTION. Error Message: Disconnected from node 0
2023-08-01 14:46:00.754  WARN 1 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition file_upload-1 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NetworkException: Disconnected from node 0. Going to request metadata update now
```

How can i fix it?